# Autolayout of View Controller View in a Container

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I have an NSWindow that has 2 container views within it, all in one xib, like so:

[image: Screenshot 1]

In another xib, I have a the view for the sidebar, managed by a different view controller, like so:

[image: Screenshot 2]

When I add the subview to the container view, I do it like this:

```
self.sidebarViewController.view.frame = self.sidebarContainer.bounds;
[self.sidebarContainer addSubview:self.sidebarViewController.view];
```

When I build and run, and resize this window, this is what happens:

[image: Screenshot 3]

The container tracks the height of it's superview properly, but the sidebar view itself does not track the height of the container.

How can I set things up so that the height of the sidebarVCs' view tracks the height of the container as the window is resized?

---

I think I've solved it like so:

```
[self.sidebarViewController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSLayoutConstraint *w = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.sidebarViewController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant:150.0];

NSArray *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|"
                                        options:0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:@{ @"view":self.sidebarViewController.view }];
[self.sidebarContainer addConstraints:c1];
[self.sidebarContainer addConstraint:w];
```

I still don't yet understand why the autoresizemask layout constraint doesn't do this automatically, but I think I'm closer to understanding the relationships between the views here.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if my problem is compression resistance/hugging  priority. I've played with all the combinations I can think of but I'm still having no luck.

Comment: If you're using auto-layout then setting the view frame is pointless. It will be overridden by auto layout based upon the provided constraints or lack of.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSBoxes as containers.  In your sidebar, add an NSBox inside the NSView and constrain all sides to the view.  Then when you want to swap in a view for the side bar you can call container (the NSBox object) setContentView:.